# iOS 7.1: Enterprise application distribution not working

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

I have just updated to IOS 7.1 public release, and if I go to My app store for enterprise application and I try to download the application, this gives me error:

> Cannot install applications because the certificate for example.com is not valid

But the same build is working for the previous versions of iOS up to iOS 7.0.6. Because it is new, I cannot find any information on the web.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue :(

Comment: iOS 7.1 update forced all software installation services to use the HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP. Here (http://cases.azoft.com/how-to-fix-certificate-is-not-valid-error-on-ios-7/) is Apache config that adds certificate support and code for changing links in existing *.plist files automatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of iOS 7.1 AdHoc installations of any apps require an HTTPS connection (which will therefore need a certificate).

You can read a bit more about it here... http://www.hanchorllc.com/2014/02/01/ios-7-1-requires-ad-hoc-installs-to-be-over-https/

Trying to find more info on it now...

Heres a bit more from the Apple dev forums. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/221520?tstart=0